# Is there a name for those iconic single-street towns of the American Wild West?

Tags: single-word-requests, names

Is there a term that describes these (see pictures below)

Used in sentence:  X now serve as great tourist attractions OR X are iconic symbols of the western american frontier

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try [*cowtown*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/cowtown) (sometimes *cow town*) which is a small western town usually frequented by cowboys.

Comment: You don't know that they're one street.  Just because that's all you see there doesn't meat that's all there is.  In order to support a store, a bank, a saloon, a sheriff's office, etc., there would need to be residents whose homes you don't see depicted, whose homes are therefore on other streets or roads.  Basically, if there's a downtown, a main street, a commercial district, then there is other population in that town that provides the personnel and patronage that all that requires to exist.

Comment: Allowing multi- words or phrases would yield more answers.

Comment: Look up Thurmond, West Virginia. It National Park service bought up nearly all of this town and created a nice write up about it. You may find some terms there. Here's the park service web site: https://www.nps.gov/neri/learn/historyculture/thurmond.htm

Comment: @BenjaminHarman The customers of the bank, store, saloon etc don't have to be residents of the town. Most of the areas served by the one-street towns are ranch and/or farming areas, people would leave their ranches or farms and make their way to town to conduct business, buy supplies and, occasionally have some fun. The only people who would live in the town would be the people providing the services.

Comment: Wouldn't any very small town (wild west or not) have only one street?

Comment: Pictures one and two could pass as **one-horse towns.**

Comment: "One-horse town" now has a [wider meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-horse-town), of any small, unimportant town with few amenities ([but usually rural](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one-horse_town)), but that sort of western town is definitely the origin of the term.

Comment: [Virtually] single-street settlements are labelled **linear settlements** [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_settlement)]

Answer (score 2):

That would colloquially be called a **one-horse town,** [defined by Wiktionary as:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/one-horse_town)

> (US, idiomatic) A very small town, especially one of a rural nature and/or offering very few or no attractions.

Answer (score 0):

125 000 hits in a raw Google search for **one-street town** probably justify its being regarded as a compound, and certainly at least a strong collocation.

One example is: -

> - *The one street town of Nindigully, Australia*

[[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/6azqv2/people_from_rural_one_street_towns_whats_on_that/)] ... although admittedly the term 'one street town' is given scare-quotes (to signify a *mooted* term) in the thread heading.